# Visual Studio 2015 CTP TypeScript Errors on Build

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, definitelytyped, typescript1.4

I am getting the following errors when using Visual Studio 2015 CTP and trying to use TypeScript.

```
1>VSTSC : error TS5015: Build: Unsupported locale: 'en-US'.
1>VSTSC : error TS5023: Build: Unknown option 'noEmitOnError'
```

I was able to get both errors to go away by setting the following configurations in the **csproj** file

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.4</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
<TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>false</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
<TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>--sourcemap --target ES5</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
```

However if I include any **DefinitelyTyped** typing files such as Angular or jQuery it will throw a bunch of errors. The errors appear to be that it doesn't understand the TypeScript 1.4 syntax for multiple value typings.

Example:

```
search(search: string, paramValue: string|number|string[]|boolean): ILocationService;
```

**Error**: Build: ',' expected

Is this a bug in Visual Studio 2015 CTP or just something messed up in my configuration.

Comment: I resolved the issue by downloading the source version from GitHub of TypeScript and putting the /bin directory into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript

Comment: Also worth noting that I had to copy the en directory from the 1.4 directory and put it in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript directory. Then rename it to en-US in order to remove the Unsupported locale error. But I no longer needed specific the csproj settings

Comment: any update on this one, having the same issue after using visual studio 2015 for a vs 2013 solution.

Answer (score 6):

I just had this occur for me when I installed TypeScript 1.8.6 Visual Studio 2015 plugin.

Eventually I fixed it by uninstalling all previous versions of TypeScript (of which I had many) using Add/Remove programs, and then reinstalling TypeScript plugin 1.8.6.

Comment: Same issue here - had to remove any older versions as well as reinstall 1.8.6 afterwords. I had **TypeScript Tools for Visual Studio 2015** 1.7.6.0. Once uninstalled and latest version reinstalled - builds worked fine again.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by re-running the TypeScript 1.4 for Visual Studio 2013 installer, copying the GitHub sources into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript" didn't work for me.