# Visual Studio 2015 update 2 throws VSTSC error during project build

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular, typescript1.8

I am trying to make an **Angular2 application with TypeScript** in

- Visual Studio 2015 with update 2 (professional edition)

I have selected **'HTML Application with Typescript template'** as suggested in this post - http://www.tonylunt.com/angular-2/angular-2-in-visual-studio-2015/

When trying to build the template project itself, i.e. without making any changes to any file, it throws the following error:

> VSTSC : error TS5023: Build: Unknown option 'noEmitOnError'

When I added **TypeScript Configuration file (tsconfig.json)**, and build the solution again, it throws following two error:

> 1. VSTSC : Error : Build: Unknown option 'project' TypeScriptApp1
> 2. VSTSC : Error : Build: Cannot resolve referenced file: 'C:\Users\hsh3\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TypeScriptApp1\TypeScriptApp1\tsconfig.json'

I checked for the 'tsconfig.json' file and it is there in the same path as mentioned in the error above.
Please check the image from the link showing the structure of my application and error that I mentioned above.
[Error during build in HTML Application With TypeScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuAYU.jpg)

I have searched on google for the same and found this one link

- [Visual Studio 2015 CTP TypeScript Errors on Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246233/visual-studio-2015-ctp-typescript-errors-on-build)

Going by the post, I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the TypeScript Visual Studio Plugin but it didn't solve the issue. I even tried repairing my VS 2015 but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repaired the Visual Studio 2015 update 2 setup and restarted the system. Now it is working all fine.
Initially I tried with installing and reinstalling of TypeScript plugin but that didn't work for me. Though I found that it works for other people having same problem as mentioned here [Visual Studio 2015 CTP TypeScript Errors on Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246233/visual-studio-2015-ctp-typescript-errors-on-build)